# Object-Relational-Mapping in Video Games

Tags: database, model-view-controller, orm

Is this common at all, or even useful? Let's say I build a 2-Dimensional RPG using ORM architecture in an MVC pattern, for example. Are there benefits?

Comment: Well, my answer would be : NO. If you want the longer answer, read this old [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7765070/redbean-orm-perfomance/7767323#7767323), repeating the same song'n'dance again would seem a bit wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ORM is a typical business software pattern, not something used in game. I guess you could use an ORM for loading the levels from a database and use it to save the current status when the game is quit. But that wouldn't be the main focus of the application. A typical business application's focus is to manage data, so the ORM takes a central role. In the game, the focus should be on the user interface.

Using an MVC approach to building user interfaces is almost always good. It keeps the user interface code structured.